# Анимированный Expander с текстом внутри теряет производительность

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6

Суть в чем, надо вывести на экран небольшой список, который содержит в себе название и описание, само описание не очень большое, но места занимает на экране, из-за чего было принято решение это все грамотно скрыть при помощи простого `Expander`. Но есть одна противная вещь, которая рушит все планы, а именно падение производительности приложения, если `Expander` будет с анимацией раскрытия, да еще и с текстом внутри, у которого установлен `Wrap` (переход на новую строку).

Набросал простой пример:

**XAML:**

```xml
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Expander Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  />
                    </Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**Код окна:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; } = new();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        TestRun();
    }

    private async void TestRun()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            var text = "Очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень\n очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень \nочень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень\n очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень \nочень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень длинный текст.";
            Items.Add(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Если так запустить, то все будет как положено, но если мы хотим анимировать `Expander`, то мы получим завсание приложения на несколько сек. Для примера возьму первую попавшуюся анимацию с интернета, получим такой XAML:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <!--  Animated Expander Button's Template  -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="AnimatedExpanderButtonTemp" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Border
            x:Name="ExpanderButtonBorder"
            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="Transparent" />
                <Ellipse
                    Name="Circle"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Width="20"
                    Height="20"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Stroke="DarkGray" />
                <Path
                    x:Name="Arrow"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 8,1.5"
                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                    Stroke="#FF666666"
                    StrokeThickness="2">
                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                </Path>
                <ContentPresenter
                    x:Name="HeaderContent"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="4,0,0,0"
                    ContentSource="Content" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <!--  Animate arrow when toggled  -->
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                To="180"
                                Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                To="0"
                                Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>

            <!--  MouseOver, Pressed behaviours  -->
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Circle" Property="Stroke" Value="#FF3C7FB1" />
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Stroke" Value="#222" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Circle" Property="Stroke" Value="#FF526C7B" />
                <Setter TargetName="Circle" Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1.5" />
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Stroke" Value="#FF003366" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <!--  Simple Expander Template  -->
    <!--
        Stretch Out Content Expander's Template,
        Uses: AnimatedExpanderButtonTemp from above
    -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="StretchyExpanderTemp" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <DockPanel>
            <ToggleButton
                x:Name="ExpanderButton"
                Padding="1.5,0"
                Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                Template="{StaticResource AnimatedExpanderButtonTemp}" />
            <ContentPresenter
                x:Name="ExpanderContent"
                ContentSource="Content"
                DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0" />
                </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
            </ContentPresenter>
        </DockPanel>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderContent"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                To="1"
                                Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderContent"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                To="0"
                                Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>

        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Expander Margin="5" Template="{StaticResource StretchyExpanderTemp}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

В основном проекте все немного иначе, там используется библиотека [WPF UI](https://github.com/lepoco/wpfui), с ее стилями, анимациями, контролами, а в основе компонента для вывода текста применяется [MdXaml](https://github.com/whistyun/MdXaml) для поддерживания Markdown форматирования (есть и другие, пробовал почти все возможные, суть не меняет).

Собственно, **вопрос**: Как решить проблему с падением производительности?

А да, при чем тут `Wrap`? А при том, что если мы его убираем, то приложение подвиснет на долю сек, а если поставить допустим `TextWrapping="Wrap"`, то оно зависнет на несколько секунд (в зависимости от числа объектов и длины текста).

Comment: Очевидно тормозня из-за того что вы заставляете `TextBlock` свои размеры пересчитывать на каждый кадр анимации. А вот как вылечить - надо подумать, гляну поближе чуть позже. Поэкспериментируйте пока с фиксированными или минимальными размерами текстблока, не обязательно пиксельными. Думаю что прибитие ширины гвоздями к чему-нибудь должно помочь.

Comment: @aepot То, что идет пересчет это очевидно, да, но, не понятно почему вообще запускается анимация, если по умолчанию `Expander` закрыт, там ведь анимация запускается по триггеру открытия (`Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"`). Что касается размеров - пробовал, действительно, лаги снижаются, но не пропадают вовсе. Допусти если в примере выше поставить у текста `Width="100" Height="100"`, то ~2 сек будет висеть окно, а не сек 10+ как без размеров, но это всеж костыль как по мне, да и который не решает проблему (не каждый захочет лагучее приложение использовать)

Comment: Так цель подергать размеры была скорее чтобы выяснить, куда копать, чем брать как решение. Я пока до кода не смог добраться, наверное завтра попробую потыкать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идею утащил [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42361229/12888024).

Дело в том что `LayoutTransform` - очень дорогая штука графически, а так же жрёт кучу ресурсов при анимации, да и выглядит неочень, визуально сплющивает контент во время анимации.

Анимировать очевидно надо высоту, если изменять надо высоту. Но чтобы анимировать высоту для `DoubleAnimation` надо задать "откуда" и "куда" в пикселях, а без костылей в код-бихайнде оперировать реальной высотой контента `ActualHeight` не получится, как минимум потому что значение для анимации нельзя ни к чему прибиндить.

Но есть способ это ограничение объехать. Хитрость заключается в том, что буду анимировать не высоту, а некое число от 0 до 1, точно так же как это сделано вами с трансформой, засуну его в `Tag`, вы уж потом посмотрите, куда лучше. А конвертером пересчитаю это в реальную высоту.

Для пересчета сотворил вот такой мульти-конвертер:

```
public class MultiplyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
        => values[0] is double height ? height * (double)values[1] ? 0.0;

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
        => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

И добавил его в ресурсы окна

```xml
<local:MultiplyConverter x:Key="MultiplyConverter"/>
```

Далее взял презентер, в котором лежит контент, и сделал его вот так

```xml
<ContentPresenter
    x:Name="ExpanderContent"
    ContentSource="Content"
    DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
    Visibility="Collapsed"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <ContentPresenter.Tag>
        <sys:Double>0.0</sys:Double>
    </ContentPresenter.Tag>
    <ContentPresenter.MaxHeight>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiplyConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
            <Binding Path="Content.ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
            <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </ContentPresenter.MaxHeight>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Где `sys` это `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`. Беру высоту того что лежит в контенте, просто отладкой откопал, где есть правильная высота. Может есть где-то поближе, поищите.

А анимации получились вот такие

```xml
<Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                    Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderContent"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0:0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderContent"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag"
                    To="1"
                    Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderContent"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag"
                    To="0"
                    Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderContent"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0:4">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
```

Фокус с `Visibility` добавлен чтобы не тормозило при прогрузке контента, и не влияло на производительность отрисовки при ресайзе окна. То же самое про `SnapsToDevicePixels`.

Что касается самой анимации - работает как надо, не фризит, не лагает.

Comment: При использовании ваших правок, окно продолжает терять производительность, но заметно меньше, да. Сейчас оно зависает на ~сек, раньше могло сек 10 висеть. Также ужасная производительность при ресайзе основного окна, все очень ужасно подвисает, даже с правками выше. `но этот же лаг я прослеживаю при подгрузке в обычные экспандеры, которын без стилей` - а вот тут не совсем так, ибо если убрать стиль с експандера, то ресайз работает гладко, а данные прогружаются моментально (фриз если и есть то буквально на пару мс.), но со стилем, это прям ужас) Так что увы, не подходит такое решение.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в таком случае нужен более реалистичный воспроизводимый пример. Я со своей стороны не вижу тех лагов, о которых говорите. Дополните вопрос.

Comment: Хм, а я ничего и не менял, весь код в вопросе (за исключением правок из ответа), проект .NET6, даже вот могу дать [эту демку](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/orHV5j-NWj3AdA) в которой чисто будет то, что в вопросе. Ну а вот [гифки](https://imgur.com/a/vH6Kp7G) того, что происходит у меня, где первая - експандер со стилем, там видно, что я двигаю окно и через 5 сек окно фризит, ну и ресайз очень медлит; ну а вторая - я убрал вообще стиль с експандера, там я без проблем двигаю и зависаний почти нет, включая ресайз.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ обновил ответ. На всякий случай, протестируйте в релизной сборке изменение размеров окна, так как у меня на релизе окно шевелится бодрее при открытых экспандерах.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ глянул в нативный шаблон, нашел там `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` на `ExpanderContent` висит, возможно это тоже добавит бодрости. Обновил хвост ответа.

Comment: Со скрытием лучше, да, поведение, как и без стилей. Только есть одно НО, нету плавной анимации раскрытия/закрытия) Другими словами, это решение равноценно тому, когда мы просто убираем стили с экспандера, что делает его без анимаций, отзывчивым и хорошим.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ как выражается отсутствие плавности? У меня она вполне себе плавная, линейная. Можно на сами анимации кривых навесить. Я кстати пересел таки на MaxHeight, потому что Height при ресайзе не пересчитывается. Снап к пикселям добавили? Обновил XAML на `MaxHeight`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у меня 4к моник и возможно видюха пободрее вашей, поэтому я могу не видеть того, о чем сейчас вы говорите.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ кстати, заметил одну интересную вещь. Беру чистый проект, беру экспандеры без стилей - открываю все, тестирую - идеально на ресайзах. Беру вставляю родной темплейт экспандера в XAML средствами редактора через контекстное меню, запускаю ничего не меняя - тормозит открытый экспандер. Запускаю в релизной сборке - все снова ок. Видимо в недрах WPF нативный XAML уже откомпилирован и ведет себя быстрее в дебаг-сборке. Именно поэтому я посоветовал проверить релизную сборку.

Comment: Ох е, это я дурак, да. Я забыл, что для тестов с експандера стиль убрал, забыв вернуть обратно. Да, анимация есть, все вроде как надо, без лагов. Спасибо. Теперь надо бы как-то перенести это на основной проект, переписав стиль библиотеки (интересно, возможно это сделать грамотно без скачивания ее исходников? Наследование стилей?). Поковыряюсь тут немного и, если проблем не возникнет, приму ответ.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ сейчас специально протестил со стилем и без стиля ресайз окна, ведет себя одинаково в релизной сборке по перфу, даже на всех полностью открытых руками экспандерах что нативный экспандер, что стилизованный, ведут себя одинаково. Обновил ответ, вмержил обновление в основное решение.

Comment: Не, все нормально, это я, как и сказал выше дурак, снял стиль с экспандера (удалил строку `Template="{StaticResource StretchyExpanderTemp}"`), ожидая там анимаций) У меня в голове было почему-то то, что стиль стоит, а когда изменил анимацию я просто получал сразу открытие/закрытие, без каких-либо анимаций (дефолтный экспандер). Вернул стиль, все как положено стало. Вот сегодня на реальный проект переносить буду, надеюсь там этот финт ушами сработает)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ отлично, рад что все идет по плану :)

Comment: Смог на основном проекте подогнать все как надо, вроде работает без проблем. Спасибо за ответ! Единственное, привязка к `Content.ActualHeight` иногда выдает `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`, отбросил эти значения в конверторе простым `if (values.Any(x => x == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)) return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;` и вроде без проблем отрабатывает.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ можно проще `=> values[0] is double height ? height * (double)values[1] ? 0.0;`, так по перфу легче будет.

Comment: Возможно. Я тут больше наверно в сторону универсальности конвертора смотрел, авось пригодиться потом еще где)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ для универсальности можно оба значения сматчить, тогда конвертер вообще будет неубиваемый, а в вашем случае только DP.Unset проверяется, а ведь может какой-нибудь `null` прилететь. Наставивать не буду.)

Comment: Ломается поиск актуального размера контента, если взять допустим `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` с вложенным `FlowDocument` (например, как [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/15.2.php)) в качестве контента `ActualHeight` у него попросту 0. Есть идеи, как это грамотно обыграть?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ завернуть его в панель? Кроме `ActulHeight` есть еще `DesiredSize`, можно потыкаться отладчиком. А так, выглядит как баг WPF.

Comment: По умолчанию обернуто в `Border`, под отладкой у него Height по нулям, причем все, даже `DesiredSize.Height`, аналогично с самим `ContentPresenter`. Единственное что помогло - "сломать" эту привязку, написав там белеберду, тогда в конвертор идет `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` и он же возвращается обратно, это вот выводит `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` как надо.